# How to stop ICS users from downloading my app

Tags: android

The app that I have in the store right now does not work quite right in ICS. While I fix it I would like to block users who have ICS from downloading and buying it. I emailed Google and they say that this is possible but they are vague about how to do it. I know how to put a Minimum SDK so that only people who have version x or above can download the app, but I cannot seem to locate how to do that in reverse. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Define `android:maxSdkVersion` in your manifest to restrict the upper limit.

For example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Now the app will only be available for devices running **Froyo** and **Gingerbread** versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

You can set filters in the market. i.e. ICS user wont see your app ^^

Use `android:maxSdkVersion="13"` in your manifest

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) page on the Android Developers documentation.

Just as you can set a minimum SDK version, you can set a maximum SDK version:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `maxSdkVersion` with the `uses-sdk` tag in the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file. It is documented in the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max).

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```